# How do I send data to JSON''s property in jade(pug)?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

At first, I send data to Jade template in Nodejs.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var arr = new Array(
        {firstname: 'Gil-dong', lastname: 'Hong'},
        {firstname: 'Yeong-sil', lastname: 'Jang'}
    );
    var jsonEncode = JSON.stringify(arr);
    var jsonDecode = JSON.parse(jsonEncode);
    res.render('/show', {arr: jsonDecode, prop: 'firstname'});
});
```

Next, I want to get 'prop' for arr's property.(in Jade template)

1)

```
div= arr[0].prop
```

2)

```
div= arr[0].#{prop}
```

3)

```
var p = !{JSON.stringify(prop)}
div= arr[0].p
```

But nothing works.
How can I send data to JSON's property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` to access JavaScript Object property by a variable, so change your code to `div= arr[0][prop]`